# Facebook Like Button not working consistently

Tags: facebook

Not sure HOW this is happening as it doesnt seem like we made any changes that would of affected this. All of a sudden about a week ago the like button stopped working on some pages. Hitting the like button would just briefly show your like and then reset to empty.

Using the Linter i get this error message "Error Creating Page  You must specify a URL as part of this widget or API."

```
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ranker.com%2Flist%2Ftop-25-worst-dressed-video-game-characters-_2011-edition_%2Fadamthomas
```

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: FYI, posted bug here at FB http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15785) has been fixed.